# How To Find 3 Backslashes in a String?

Tags: c#

I can't find a way to find 3 backslashes in a string like the following...

```
<div><div class=\\\"entry-content\\\">
```

Here is my code...

```
string str1 = "<div><div class=\\\"entry-content\\\">";
int k = str1.IndexOf(@"\\\"); // returns -1
```

Basically, I'm trying to replace 3 backslashes with 1 backslash like in the code below which doesn't work because k is -1

```
str1 = str1.Replace(@"\\\", @"\");
```

I want the string to be this `"<div><div class=\"entry-content\">"`

Answer (score 4):

Your string has only one backslash.

```
\\\" = \"
```

So the first one escapes the second backslash. And third backslash escapes the double quote. Result is one backslash and a double quote.

If you want your string to contain all backslashes without escaping use a verbatim string:

```
string str1 = @"<div><div class=\\\""entry-content\\\"">";
```

You can read more about escaping and escape sequences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences).